# How to jump to a directory using cd and ls (to select column and item)?

Tags: shell-script

I wanted to use cd with ls to change directory to `Typescript-initial-config-with-eslint/`:

```
package.json  README.md  tsconfig.json  Typescript-initial-config-with-eslint/
public/       **src/**       tslint.json    yarn.lock
```

like:

```
cd ls | (4° item)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking.  You want to cd into the directory and then execute `ls`?  Or you want to execute `ls` in the current directory and then change to the directory?  What decides which directory you change into?  The most effective way to do it would be `cd Typescript-initial-config-with-eslint`

Comment: I just wanna use ls to select a string directory and put it inside cd so that I not type so much words. I just wanna select a item from ls, only this, for educational purposes too. I wouldn't type so much to change directory if the directory name is big.

Comment: use tab completion: `cd T`<tab>

Comment: @jesse_b nice. but and if I could do the way I was thinking: selecting a string from ls and use it all in one command with cd? for doubt purpose

Comment: The code in your example (after the like), will not work. What is it supposed to show?

Comment: Are you asking "how do I `cd` to 4th item in `ls` list?" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could use a select loop:

```
select dir in *; do cd -- "$dir"; break; done
```

However that is actually more typing than just using `cd` normally, but you could make a function out of it:

```
cdls () {
    local PS3='cdls>'
    select dir in *; do
        if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
            cd -- "$dir"
            break
        else
            printf '%s\n' "You can only cd into a directory" >&2
        fi
    done
}
```

There also isn't much use in showing non-directory files in the first place since you can't `cd` into them so you could just do:

```
cdls () {
    local PS3='cdls>'
    select dir in */; do
            cd -- "$dir"
            break
    done
}
```

Comment: How can I use this function forever in my shell?

Comment: @JulianoHenrique: You would add it to your `~/.bashrc` file (assuming bash is your default shell)

Answer (score 1):

If you asking "How do I `cd` to 4th item in `ls` list?", then

```
cd "$(ls | tail -n +6 | head -n 1)"
```